# SQL Server 2016 Severity 015 Not Alerting

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to setup an alert in SQL Server 2016 for Severity 015 (syntax errors in SQL statements) however it will not fire off. I can generate the error with a bad SQL statement in query.

I have confirmed DB Mail is working and test messages come in as expected. EMail setup and valid operator in place. I was also able to generate a 017 Alert (insufficient resources) error and get alerted with no problem using the following:

```
RaisError (N'An error occurred Severity 17: insufficient resources ! ', 17, 1)
With Log
Go
```

FYI, the reason I need this alerting is we are converting from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016 and older commands like `*=` are all over the place. Need to know when they are coming in because of being missed somewhere.

Thanks in advance for any guidance and help.

Comment: Use `THROW`, like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says.

Comment: I would need to know where all the code is with the issues, and if I knew that I would just change the code to be correct.  My objective is to capture when the broken code commands are sent.

Comment: Don't get confused by my code sample.  I just wanted individuals to know that alerts, email, etc. was up and working.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the server fault SE if you're not getting an answer here (I can't help, sorry)

Comment: Hi Exelian, new to Stacked Overflow, so not sure what Server Fault SE is.  Can you help clarify?

Comment: *"insufficient resources !"* does not mean "Syntax error". If you're getting errors with syntax errors, they will already be telling you where they are in the code with the line number.